# Как проверить пароль в Delphi если он создан в PHP функцией password_hash()

Tags: php, delphi

У меня есть самописный сайт на PHP. База данных MySQL.
Столкнулся с необходимостью создать приложение на Delphi. Которое будет работать с этой же БД.

Для того что-бы защитить пароли пользователей я их захешировал функцией  password_hash() в PHP.

```
//Шифрование пароля
        $user['password'] = password_hash($user['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

На Delphi Планирую реализовать таким образом:
На форме два поля ввода. Edit1 и Edit2. И кнопка.
После нажатия на кнопку данные с поля Edit2 хешируются и формируется запрос в бд.

У меня проблема с хешированием в Delphi. Я использовал Bcrypt.pas но у меня ничего не получилось.

Я ищу одинаковый метод хеширования для Delphi и PHP.
ПОдскажите пли.

Comment: Придётся делать отдельный запрос к сайту для проверки пароля

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду средствами Delphi отправить данные Post запросом и результат проверить? Отличная идея.

Comment: Видимо легче поставить PHP и в фоновом режиме в php-скрипте генерировать нужный тебе password_hash (из delphi запускаем php и забираем результат).

Comment: В принципе теоретически ничего не мешает написать на Delphi функцию с поведением, аналогичным password_hash/password_verify (но это не слишком просто и лично мне лень)

Answer (score 0):

Использовал материал по [ссылке](http://fegorsk.ru/index.php/studentam/delphi/25-avtorizatsiya-na-sajte-sredstvami-delphi)

В результате у меня 2е формы. На первой два Edit, button, idhttp, idcookiemanager, idantifreeze.

```
procedure TLogin.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  str: TStringList; // Переменная в которой будем формировать запрос на сайт
  bufer: string;
  // В этих переменных будем хранить те самые пару значений из переловленного запроса.
begin
  IdHTTP1.Request.AcceptCharSet := 'windows-1251';

  str := TStringList.Create;
  // Формируем POST запрос
  str.Add('login='+ Edit1.text); // Добавляем в запрос переменную username
  str.Add('password='+ Edit2.text); // Добавляем в запрос переменную password
  bufer := IdHTTP1.Post('http://diptrace.zzz.com.ua/auth/signin', str);
  // Сформированный Post запрос отправляем на сервер, адрес мы узнали из перехваченнгого пакета.
  bufer := IdHTTP1.Get('http://diptrace.zzz.com.ua/CP/');
  if Pos('Выход', bufer) > 1 then
  // На странице должна появиться кнопка с надписью "Выйти".
  begin
    Form2.Visible:=true;
    Login.Visible:=false;
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('Проверьте Логин/пароль'); // Если не все - то не ок
  str.Destroy;


end;
```

Ну а далее я планирую работать уже напрямую с БД.

Comment: http считается небезопасным, нужно стараться https использовать (особенно для паролей).